# Searching for a website about creating databases

Tags: database

What websites do you know about developing DB?

It should have a lot of examples(e.g. file-store architecture, meta-data db, data-warehouse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the [database entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) on wikipedia?  Or the MS SQL Server [examples](http://www.codeplex.com/SqlServerSamples) on CodePlex?

Comment: thx. above an beyond I want to see real implementation not only theoretical material.
best regards.

Comment: @Sergii - I added a link to some sample MSSQL DBs on CodePlex.